# Size of .jpg and .jpeg increased after compression

Tags: python, k-means, image-compression

I am trying to compress the images using the K-means algorithm but the size of some .jpg images have increased after compression. How can I do it for .jpg and .jpeg images. I have saved the jpg and jpeg images in png format before applying the compression

```
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        image = io.imread(f,0)
        rows = image.shape[0]
        cols = image.shape[1]

        pixels = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
        kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=128, n_init=10, max_iter=200)
        kmeans.fit(pixels)

        clusters = np.asarray(kmeans.cluster_centers_, dtype=np.uint8)
        labels = np.asarray(kmeans.labels_, dtype=np.uint8)
        labels = labels.reshape(rows, cols)
        colored = clusters[labels]

        #  np.save('codebook'+f+'.npy', clusters)
        io.imsave('compressed_' + f, colored)

        img1 = mpimg.imread(f,0)
        img2 = mpimg.imread('compressed_' + f,0)
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
        ax1.imshow(img1)
        ax1.set_title('Original image')
        ax2.imshow(img2)
        ax2.set_title('Compressed image')
        plt.show()

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

        img = cv2.imread(f, 0)
        ax[0].hist(img.ravel(), 256, [0, 256]);
        ax[0].set_title("Original image")
        img1 = cv2.imread('compressed_' + f,0)
        ax[1].hist(img1.ravel(), 256, [0, 256]);
        ax[1].set_title("Compressed image")
        plt.show()

        print('size of original image: ', int(os.stat(f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
        print('size of compressed image:', int(os.stat('compressed_' + f).st_size / 1024), 'kB')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your approach correctly, you use K-means clustering to reduce the number of colors in the image by finding areas (clusters) of similar colored pixels and grouping them together.

While this can theoretically reduce the filesize of the image, saving it again as a jpeg applies a whole different image compression algorithm on the reduced image, which cannot take full advantage of big areas of the same color with sharp edges. It will necessarily "blur" the image, and in some cases, this can even lead to an increased file size.

Try storing the reduced image in a different format (e.g. as a png file), that can make use of big, evenly colored areas.

Comment: I have converted the jpeg files into png before applying the compression algorithm but still, the images are of larger size.

Comment: Without access to your sample image I don't think anything more detailed or specific can be stated. Perhaps you could make your program print more information about what it actually does. How many clusters did it find, how large are they, what did it do with them?

Comment: @SamratShrestha - it is not about the filetype of the image *before* compression, it is about the filetype you use to store the compressed image. If you used the most elaborate compression algorithm and store the results as a bmp file, you would throw everything gained by your compression algorithm away. Same thing can happen (on a much smaller scale) when saving as jpeg.

Comment: If you have posted your sample image somewhere, you forgot to tell us where. Repeating text from the question in a comment seems rather superfluous.

Comment: Sorry, I added it.

Comment: Since you don't specify the compression quality for the encoding of your result as a jpeg, the default (75%) is used. If your original image was already compressed with a lower quality, this can lead to a bigger filesize. When using the image you inserted in your post (which is a jpg) and executing your code, the filesize shrinks from 108187 to 96223.

Comment: But how were you able to shrink the image? Did you convert it into jpeg?